# Popular inputs com jquery e inserir linhas de tabela ao mesmo tempo

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tenho um input que quando inserida a matricula (identificação) de uma pessoa, o restante da tabela popula dinamicamente, e é inserido automaticamente outra linha da tabela, que funcionaria da mesma forma, insere-se a matricula e o restante da linha completa novamente e assim por diante. Porém apenas a primeira linha funciona, as demais não, e não faço ideia de como resolver. Segue o código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var x = 0;
        $(document).on('blur', 'input[name="matBusca['+ x +']"]' ,function(){
            var y = x + 1;
            $('#listas').append('\
            <tr><td><input type="text" name="matBusca['+ y +']"></td>\
            <td><input type="text" name="nomeBusca['+ y +']"></td>\
            <td><input type="text" name="cargoBusca['+ y +']"></td>\
            <td><input type="text" name="clpdBusca['+ y +']"></td>\
            ');
            $("input[name='matBusca["+ y +"]']").focus();
            var $nome = $("input[name='nomeBusca["+ x +"]']");
            var $cargo = $("input[name='cargoBusca["+ x +"]']");
            var $clpd = $("input[name='clpdBusca["+ x +"]']");
            $nome.val('Carregando...');
            $cargo.val('Carregando...');
            $clpd.val('Carregando...');
            $.getJSON(
                'function.php',
                { matBusca: $( this ).val() },
                function( json ){
                    $nome.val( json.nome );
                    $cargo.val( json.cargo );
                    $clpd.val( json.clpd );
                }
            );
            x++;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que só o `input[name="matBusca[0]"]` vai reagir ao `blur` pois quando a linha `$(document).on('blur', 'input[name="matBusca['+ x +']"]' ,function(){` é lida o `x` tem o valor de zero.

Tens de fazer com que esse delegador `input[name="matBusca['+ x +']"]` aceite os outros também.

A solução é usar `^=` que diz ao jQuery para usar seletores *"que comecem com"*. No teu caso poderia ser `input[name^="matBusca"]`.

#### Exemplo:

```js
$(document).on('blur', 'input[name^="foo"]', function() {
  console.log(this.name);
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="foo[0]">
<input type="text" name="foo[1]">
<input type="text" name="foo[2]">
<input type="text" name="foo[3]">
```

Comment: Acho que podias limpar o teu código um pouco mais e ficar assim: https://jsfiddle.net/jxbbvsa4/

Comment: Sergio muito obrigado, deu certo aqui.